# XKB error on a MacBook Pro 4.1 causes keyboard problems

Tags: 11.04, keyboard-layout, mac

I have just installed the newest version of the ubuntu on my Macbook Pro. Right from the start, after I had done the upgrade, the OS showed a error window with the following message:

> Error activating XKB configuration.
>  It can happen under various
>   circumstances:
>   • a bug in libxklavier library
>   • a bug in X
>   server (xkbcomp, xmodmap utilities)
>   • X server with incompatible
>   libxkbfile implementation
>  X server version data:
>  The X.Org
>   Foundation
>  11001000
>  If you report this situation as a bug,
>   please include:
>   • The result of xprop -root | grep XKB
>   •
>   The result of gconftool-2 -R
>   /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd

Here are the results of the commands in the last two lines:

```
$ xprop -root | grep XKB
_XKB_RULES_NAMES_BACKUP(STRING) = "evdev", "applealu_ansi", "pt", "mac", "grp:shift_caps_toggle,grp_led:caps"
_XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "applealu_ansi", "pt", "mac", "grp:shift_caps_toggle,grp_led:caps"

$ gconftool-2 -R /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd
 layouts = [pt  mac,pt]
 model = 
 options = []
```

Plus, the keyboard is all messed up! And I tried to change the keyboard layout and configuration, but it shows the same error message.

I don't know if there is anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have Macbook 7.1 and experienced same problems.

My Solution was to remove the **Intl-Variant** from the keyboard layout and choose the standard instead.

```
$ gnome-keyboard-properties
```

1. Click Tab Layouts
2. Click Button Add... (new window opens)
3. Click Tab By County
4. Country: Select e.g. "Germany"
5. Variants: Select e.g. "Germany"

   *NOTE:* Do not select Variant e.g. "Germany Macintosh"!
6. Click Button Add (window closes)
7. Select other Layouts and remove them from the list

   Select e.g. "Germany"
   Keyboard Model: Select "MacBook/MacBook Pro"